# Avoid Microsoft login popup through powershell script

Tags: powershell, dynamics-crm, powerapps

I am running below powershell script to enable Admin mode for powerapp environment (dynamics 365 crm) before Production deployment. I want to schedule this script to trigger before deployment, but every time it pops up for credential and that is not possible to provide credentials if it is running as a scheduled task.

Powershell script:

```
Set-AdminPowerAppEnvironmentRuntimeState -EnvironmentName "environment guid" -RuntimeState AdminMode
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague and possibly missing some lines. Are you connecting to PowerApps before you run this command?

```
# Here is how you can pass in credentials (avoiding opening a prompt)
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
Add-PowerAppsAccount -Username foo@bar.com -Password $pass
```

https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/gdpr-admin-powershell-cmdlets/